# Snowflake Timestamp column not loaded using Copy Command

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, to-timestamp

I am using Copy command to load a file in table. It has a timestamp column.

In my File format I have defined Timestamp as other and gave value as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM
to match with data.

When I execute it loads all records which have timestamp with AM format and any records with timestamp of PM time fails in Copy.

Sample fail record:
1, abc, 04/12/2016 12:00:00 PM

Sample successfully Loaded Record:
2, erd, 04/12/2016 08:00:00 AM

To verify my timestamp format I used below query and it worked fine:
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('04/12/2016 12:00:00 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')

Answer (score 0):

The `AM` in your format definition is for `HH12` not `HH24` and is otherwise just considered a literal string.  Try explicitly using `HH12` in your format definition and see if that resolves your issue.  I agree that it should behave the same as `TO_TIMESTAMP()` but since it isn't, I'd try to follow the guidelines of the documentation in your file format.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions